# transform Csv file to list of lists with python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to be able to turn csv file into a list of lists .
my csv file is like that :

```
['juridiction', 'audience', 'novembre'],['récapitulatif', 'information', 'important', 'octobre'],['terrain', 'entent', 'démocrate'],['porte-parole', 'tribunal', 'monastir', 'farid ben', 'déclaration', 'vendredi', 'octobre', 'télévision', 'national', 'mère', 'fillette', 'an', 'clandestinement', 'italie', 'juge', 'instruction', 'interrogatoire', 'père'],['disposition', 'décret', 'vigueur', 'premier', 'octobre'],['décret', 'loi', 'numéro', '2022', 'octobre', 'disposition', 'spécial', 'amélioration', 'efficacité', 'réalisation', 'projet', 'public', 'priver', 'jort', 'vendredi', 'octobre'],['avocat', 'rahal jallali', 'déclaration', 'vendredi', 'octobre', 'tap', 'militant', 'membre', 'section', 'bardo', 'ligue', 'droit', 'homme', 'membre', 'association', 'damj', 'saif', 'ayadi', 'jeune', 'juge', 'instruction', 'tribunal', 'instance'],...
```

into

```
list1 = [['juridiction', 'audience', 'novembre'],['récapitulatif', 'information', 'important', 'octobre'],['terrain', 'entent', 'démocrate'],['porte-parole', 'tribunal', 'monastir', 'farid ben', 'déclaration', 'vendredi', 'octobre', 'télévision', 'national', 'mère', 'fillette', 'an', 'clandestinement', 'italie', 'juge', 'instruction', 'interrogatoire', 'père'],['disposition', 'décret', 'vigueur', 'premier', 'octobre'],['décret', 'loi', 'numéro', '2022', 'octobre', 'disposition', 'spécial', 'amélioration', 'efficacité', 'réalisation', 'projet', 'public', 'priver', 'jort', 'vendredi', 'octobre'],['avocat', 'rahal jallali', 'déclaration', 'vendredi', 'octobre', 'tap', 'militant', 'membre', 'section', 'bardo', 'ligue', 'droit', 'homme', 'membre', 'association', 'damj', 'saif', 'ayadi', 'jeune', 'juge', 'instruction', 'tribunal', 'instance'],...]]
```

Ive try to solve this but no  success :

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/tokens.csv') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    res = list(zip_longest(*rows))
    list1 = [list(filter(None.__ne__, l)) for l in res]
    print(res2)
```

but the output is  :

```
[["['juridiction'"], [" 'audience'"], [" 'novembre']"], ["['récapitulatif'"], [" 'information'"], [" 'important'"], [" 'octobre']"], ["['terrain'"], [" 'entent'"], [" 'démocrate']"],...
```

Comment: check `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Not an answer, but this is one of those examples that shows that using actual commas in a CSV is generally not a good idea. Tabs or semi-colons (;) are safer.

Comment: @StephanT any idea please to transform commas in this csv file with (;) ?

Comment: I think you should not be using the csv library. If your source is not a file with multiple lines where every line represents a row with the same amount of columns, the csv library is not of any use. Ref. @Epsi95's comment: if the file's content is a valid python literal, you could read the whole file at once and use `ast.literal_val` to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file really consists of only one long line, then here's a couple of options:

Use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#eval): You need to add the brackets for the outer list.

```py
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    data = eval("[" + file.read().strip() + "]")
```

Use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/json.html#json.loads): You need to (1) add the outer brackets, and (2) replace the `'` with `"` to make the string json compliant.

```py
import json

with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    data = json.loads("[" + file.read().strip().replace("'", '"') + "]")
```

Use string manipulation: You need to (1) remove the brackets at the edges, then (2) remove the `'`s, then (3) `.split` anlong `"],["`, and finally (4) `.split` the parts along `", "`.

```py
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    data = [
        string.split(", ")
        for string in file.read().strip().strip("[]").replace("'", "").split("],[")
    ]
```

(Replace `data.csv` with your file path.)